# When can convolutional integral operators be sampled

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, integral-transforms, integral-kernel, sampling

Consider an integral operator $F:C^{1/2}([0,T],\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of the form
$$
f\mapsto \int_0^T f(t)^{\top}\kappa(T-t)dt,
$$
for some $\kappa\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^d)$ with the property that $\kappa(s)=0$ whenever $s<0$ or $s>T$.  Equip $C^{1/2}([0,T],\mathbb{R}^n)$ with the uniform convergence norm
$$
\|f\|:=\max_{0\le t\le T}\, \|f(t)\|_{2},
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes the Euclidean norm.

Are there conditions on $\kappa$ and on $f$ such that if $\|f\|\le 1$ then: for every $\epsilon>0$ there are points $0\le t_1\le \dots\le t_{N(\epsilon)}\le t$ such that:
$$
\max_{\|f\|\le 1}\, \Big|\int_0^T f(t)^{\top}\kappa(T-t)\,dt - \sum_{n=1}^{N(\epsilon)} f(t_n)^{\top}\kappa(T-t_n)\,dt\Big|<\epsilon?
$$

Moreover, can we ensure that $N(\epsilon)= O(\epsilon^{-1/2})$?